# Proof limit of function using Cauchy condition: $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x+1}{x-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

I have to calculate limit at 0 of that function:

$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x+1}{x-1}$

I have problem to find correct $\delta$
I've already done this:

$0\leq|\frac{x+1}{x-1}+1|<\epsilon$

$0\leq|\frac{x+1+x-1}{x-1}|<\epsilon$

$0\leq|\frac{2x}{x-1}|<\epsilon$

$0\leq2|\frac{x}{x-1}|<\epsilon$
I have no ideas what should I do next I know that

$0\leq|x|<\delta$

But what next?
How can I show that $\delta$ exists for all $\epsilon$?

Comment: If $|x|<\frac12$, you have $|x-1|>\frac12$. Can you use this further?

Comment: Without to make the last choice of delta, we make the assumption that delta is up to $\frac{1}{2}$ and then $2|\frac{x}{x-1}|<4\delta$. Thus, if we let $\delta=min\{1/2,\varepsilon /4\}$, then we have the answer of the problem.

Comment: i dont get it, why delsta is up to $\frac{1}{2}$?i know is assumption but why $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: The boundary 1/2 is not unique. You let $\delta<a$ in such a way that the neighborhood of 0 with rad $a$ to lies on the domain of the $f$ and of course to bound the $2|\frac{x}{x-1} | $from a number of the form $g(a)\delta$. Then you take as delta the minimum of $a$ and $\epsilon /g(a)$. The first assumption about delta is only about doing your job

Comment: what? $2|\frac{x}{x-1}| < 4\delta$ when $\delta$ is up to $\frac{1}{2}$ so it will be $2|\frac{x}{x-1}| < 2$ but  there are exist some x that $2|\frac{x}{x-1}|$ is greater than 2

Comment: ok i see than, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Proving for $0<\epsilon<1$ would suffice.

$|x|<\epsilon \implies 0<(1-\epsilon)<(1-x)<(1+\epsilon)
\implies 0<(1-\epsilon)<|x-1|<(1+\epsilon)
\implies \frac{1}{|x-1|}<\frac{1}{1-\epsilon}$ Here we just exploit the fact that $\frac{1}{|x-1|}$ is bounded for $|x|<\epsilon <1$.
Therefore we have 
$|\frac{x+1}{x-1}+1|=\frac{|2x|}{|x-1|}<\frac{2|x|}{(1-\epsilon)}$.
Then we have $\frac{2|x|}{(1-\epsilon)}<\epsilon$ iff $|x|<\frac{\epsilon(1-\epsilon)}{2}$.
So we take $\delta=\frac{\epsilon(1-\epsilon)}{2}$. *And clearly this $\delta$ is less than $\epsilon$  so that the inequality $\frac{1}{|x-1|}<\frac{1}{1-\epsilon}$ holds*.

Comment: $(1−\epsilon)<(1−x)<(1+\epsilon)$ what if x <-2?i thought it should work for all domain

Comment: Here all I want is how the function behaves near 0 not away from 0.

Answer (score 0):

is that way correct?
$f(x_1)=-1+e\rightarrow \frac{x_1+1}{x_1-1}=-1+e \rightarrow (x_1+1)=(-1+e)(x_1-1)\rightarrow(x_1+1)=(-x_1+1+ex_1-e)\rightarrow (2x_1-ex_1)=-e\rightarrow x_1=\frac{-\epsilon}{2-\epsilon}$

same way for $f(x_2)=-1-e$

and than i will chose lesser absolute value and this will be my $\delta$?